# Azure DevOps SSH release pipeline task and Docker Compose STDERR

Tags: azure-devops, docker-compose, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-task

I am using [Classic release pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/?view=azure-devops) in Azure DevOps and configured simple SSH task what calls docker-compose:

`cd /home/asem/platform/$(ServiceName) && sudo docker-compose up -d --force-recreate`

[image: Azure DevOps SSH release pipeline task]

[image: Azure DevOps SSH release pipeline task configuration]

**Issue**: task fails with errors:

[image: SSH task errors]

Docker-compose returns 0 exit code, but write some messages in STDERR. Pipeline task treat them as errors and fails.

**Questions**:

1. Why docker-compose designed that way what EXIT code = 0, but there are some errors were written in STDERR ?
2. Any good solution (please see found workarounds in my answer below) ?

Comment: Hi @Aleksei, thanks for your sharing! Just a remind, you could [accept your answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235), and this may help others find the answer quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Workaround 1**: pipe docker compose STDERR to STDOUT like `cd /home/asem/platform/$(ServiceName) && sudo docker-compose up -d --force-recreate 2 >&1`

*sudo docker-compose up -d --force-recreate **2 >&1***

That works, but I don’t like it because it can hide some real errors

**Workaround 2**: Uncheck “Fail on STDERR” for task

[image: SSH task unchecked Fail on STDERR]

That works, but release stage displays errors which is not good though.

[image: release stage errors]

Answer (score 1):

Will a stderr redirect + grep work for you?

```bash
docker compose up -d 2> >(grep -i error)
```

Happy path:
[image]

With error:
[image]